# XSL - change all XML Element null values to dash

Tags: xml, xslt

I have got xml which has many children and sub children. I have to go through all values of element and if there are any nulls or blank I have to change it to dash or some other value.

xml example

```
<list>
  <biglist>
   <item>1</item>
   <item>0</item>
   <item>2</item>
   <item>1</item>
   <item></item>
   <item>8</item>
   <smallList>
     <smallitem>0</smallitem>
     <smallitem></smallitem>
     <smallitem></smallitem>
     <smallitem>4</smallitem>
    </smallList>
  </biglist>
</list>
```

output

```
<div id=biglist>
   <div>1</div>
   <div>0</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>1</div>
   <div><strong> Value not found </strong></div>
   <div>8</div>
   <div id=smallList>
     <div>0</div>
    <div><strong> Value not found </strong></div>
    <div><strong> Value not found </strong></div>
    <div>4</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a small example of the input and the required output.

Comment: May we ask why? It's a strange requirement. All it accomplishes is that the downstream software has to cope with dashes or whatever instead of null or blank values, and it also introduces an ambiguity: what about existing dashes? Are you going to escape them? And escape the escapes? If this requirement isn't your own invention you should ask those questions: in fact you should ask yourself those questions even if it is your own.

Comment: Its more of UI requirement. I need to change the value and then output to html by applying other templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to change the value and then output to html by applying other
>   templates.

That's not how XSLT works (unless you do your transformation in two passes).

Try adding the following template to your existing templates:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(* or text())]">
    <div>
        <strong> Value not found </strong>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's an example using the *identity transform* as the main template:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- exception for empty leaf nodes -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(* or text())]">
    <div>
        <strong> Value not found </strong>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
  <biglist>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <div>
      <strong> Value not found </strong>
    </div>
    <item>8</item>
    <smallList>
      <smallitem>0</smallitem>
      <div>
        <strong> Value not found </strong>
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong> Value not found </strong>
      </div>
      <smallitem>4</smallitem>
    </smallList>
  </biglist>
</list>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide an example input XML, just a possible approach you maybe can adjust to meet your input:

Example input XML:

```
<list>
  <item>1</item>
  <item>0</item>
  <item>2</item>
  <item>1</item>
  <item></item>
  <item>8</item>
</list>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
     omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item[text()='0' or not(text()[normalize-space()])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Ouput:

```
<list>
 <item>1</item>
 <item>-</item>
 <item>2</item>
 <item>1</item>
 <item>-</item>
 <item>8</item>
</list>
```

This copies all nodes but will replace the value of each node with no value or the value 0 with a dash.

In case you would like to change single occurences of space or 0 in the values with a dash, for the example input XML

```
<list>
  <item>1 1</item>
  <item>0</item>
  <item>201</item>
  <item>1</item>
  <item></item>
  <item>304</item>
  <item>8</item>
</list>
```

the following template when added in above XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="item/text()[contains(.,'0') or contains(.,' ')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'0 ','--')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

produces the output

```
<list>
  <item>1-1</item>
  <item>-</item>
  <item>2-1</item>
  <item>1</item>
  <item>-</item>
  <item>3-4</item>
  <item>8</item>
</list>
```

using `translate()`.
In this case the match pattern of the template

```
<xsl:template match="item[text()='0' or not(text()[normalize-space()])]">
```

can be adjusted to

```
<xsl:template match="item[not(text()[normalize-space()])]">
```

as for the case of `text()='0'` is already taken care of.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how would i do it if i want to change the the value in xml before applying html template for output. I can do using xsl:if for each value in each template.